# JS/jQuery: addClass to 2 divs when clicking on single div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I'm trying to make it so that when a div with an image is clicked both that div and it's related div (one with `-content`) are appended with an `.active` class (that is, when a image div is clicked it's respective content box pops-up)

http://jsfiddle.net/sergep/VM6AC/

I am unsure what I am doing wrong in the javascript section of the code:

```
$('.diagram div').click(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var type = $this.attr('class');
  $this.siblings('.diagram div').removeClass('active');
  $this.addClass('active');
  $('div.diagram-content .' + type).addClass('active');
});
```

Why is it when I add a simple `alert($this.attr('class'));` line the code stops working completely? (or does it?)

The html looks like so:

```
<div class="diagram">
  <div id="gameboy" class="gameboy"></div>
  <div class="switch"></div>
  <div class="face"></div>
</div>
<div class="anatomy-content">
  <div class="gameboy-content">This is a content box for the gameboy</div>
  <div class="switch-content">This is a content box for the switch</div>
  <div class="face-content">This is a content box for the face</div>
</div>
```

I decided to take the `classes` approach as opposed to the `data-type` approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.diagram div').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        theClass = this.className;
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $this.add($('.' + theClass + '-content')).addClass('active');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VM6AC/7/).

Incidentally, using `$this.attr('class')` doesn't fail (check the console), the problem is that you forgot to append the `-content` string to that class-name:

```
$('.diagram div').click(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var theClass = $this.attr('class');
    console.log($this,theClass);
  $this.siblings('.diagram div').removeClass('active');
  $this.addClass('active');
  $('div.diagram-content .' + theClass + '-content').addClass('active');
  //                                     ^-- this is necessary, otherwise there's no match
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VM6AC/9/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Comment: Amazingly quick and incredibly efficient. Thanks!